# How to use value of key in JOLT

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I'm looking for breaking nested JSON file and trying to flatten them to fit into a SQL database.

**Current JSON:**

```json
{
  "content": {
    "failedPerProductLineAndReason": {
      "Product1": {
        "Downsizing licenses is not allowed": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected outcome:**

```json
{
  "ErrorType": "failedPerProductLineAndReason",
  "product": "Product1",
  "error": "Downsizing licenses is not allowed",
  "quantity": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go inside the `Downsizing licenses is not allowed` and get its value by `@` and get another keys you want by `$`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // content
        "*": { // failedPerProductLineAndReason
          "*": { // Product1
            "*": { // Downsizing licenses is not allowed
              "$2": "ErrorType",
              "$1": "product",
              "$": "error",
              "@": "quantity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$** wildcards incrementally nested within objects/attribute such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "ErrorType",
          "*": {
            "$": "product",
            "*": {
              "$": "error",
              "@": "quantity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

as principally needed to extract the keys

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]